# Embedded object movie won't start playing

Tags: html, windows-media-player

I have this code:

```
<object id="MediaPlayer1" width="280" height="256" classid="clsid:6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701">
<param name="fileName" value="/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/GM-Oh.avi" />
<param name="animationatStart" value="true" />
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true" />
<param name="autoStart" value="true" />
<param name="showControls" value="true" />
<param name="Volume" value="-450" />
<param name="url" value="/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/GM-Oh.avi" />
<param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" />
<param name="autostart" value="1" />
<param name="showcontrols" value="1" />
<param name="volume" value="-450" />
<embed id="MediaPlayer1" width="280" height="256" type="application/x-mplayer2" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/GM-Oh.avi" fileName="/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/GM-Oh.avi" animationatStart="true" transparentatStart="true" autoStart="true" showControls="false" Volume="-450" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" autostart="1" showcontrols="1" volume="-450" />
</object>
```

The problem is, my movie object appears but the movie won't start playing.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Using HTML5 as you have tagged, why not using directly `<video>` and embedding inside the `object`? Something like `<video src='/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/GM-Oh.avi'>`(enter params if needed)`</video>`

Comment: Which browser and version are you using? Does the WMP plugin work correctly normally?

Comment: @poepje: In any browser it says "Error downloading codec" so I`m guessing that it`s the plugins fault.

Comment: Yes, WMP has always been meager with its codecs... Try downloading this http://download.cnet.com/Media-Player-Codec-Pack/3000-13632_4-10749065.html or perhaps a standalone codec pack like K-lite.

Comment: @Alex2k: I want a cross-browser compatible solution, HTML5 does not render ok in every browser. And besides, my movie is in avi format, I`ve tried your solution and it doesn`t show a thing type="video/x-msvideo"

Comment: @Poepje: Yes, that would probably work for me, but what about the other users that visit my site, I can`t really force them to download a codec now, can i? :)

Comment: True. I'm no expert on this but I think you would be better off not using WMP. I personally prefer the free JW player. It's a simple flash file that you can use and works fairly well with common codecs, including .avi files. Make sure you try several versions though; they all work and look very different.

Comment: @Gabriel HTML5 is still more cross-browser/platform than WMP.

Comment: @RobinJ: Do you have a suggestion on how I should embed my avi in the web page?

Comment: @Gabriel AVI files are generally very big, so for the sake of your own bandwidth, and the bandwidth of the user, I'd suggest you use the WebM format. Nobody likes having to look at a "buffering" message for 10 minutes before their video starts playing :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you change your doc type to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and use an HTML5 player.

```
<video width="280" height="256"controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/GM-Oh.avi" type="video/avi" />
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. Upgrade to <a href="http://abetterbrowser.org/">a better browser</a>.
</video>
```

You might need to convert the video file to OGG, WebM or MP4 though, as I'm not sure whether AVI will play.

More information on HTML5 video: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp